# Cannot access AWS RDS MySQL DB from CLI MySQL Linux client; works great from Navicat

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services

OK, set up a MySQL RDS DB in AWS. It is not publicly accessible. If I Putty into an EC2 box on the same subnet I can access the DB via tunnelling when I fire up Navicat.

Switch to a Linux RedHat box (running Percona 5.5.44).
I want to connect to tunnel to the RDS DB and have it available locally on port 3308 (port 3306 has a local MySQL DB already, as does 3307 [backup]).

```
telnet localhost 3308
```

returns

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

So, nothing there, which is what I expect.

Run SSH:

```
ssh -L 3308:blahblah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 -i key.ssh user@AWS_EC2box.com -f -N
```

where blahblah is the RDS server and AWS_EC2 is the EC2 server on the same subnet.

Try telnet again:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
N
5.6.23-logV[>e`3|9▒7{(SL_zgu7Rumysql_native_password
```

I know the DB I want is runnning MySQL 5.6.23, so very likely this is the DB I am seeking.

Now try:

```
mysql -P 3308 -u testuser -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

No matter which user I try, with password, without, setting plugin to mysql_old_password and using Old_Password, anything- all fails.

But I can set up with PuTTy and Navicat from my Windows PC, and get in every time- same users, same passwords. PuTTy tunnels using the same EC2 box, and goes to the same RDS box. I've torn down and re-done the connections multiple times on both sides.
No joy. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: connection refused = firewalled, or mysql isn't listening on that port. access denied = you got a connection, but didn't use the right credentials to log in.

Comment: But I use the same credentials via Navicat (username and password- without difficulty). Even tried making a connection with no password at all. Still cannot get in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'testuser'@'localhost'` in the error message is the giveaway that what you're actually doing here is not the same thing as what you intended to do.

RDS would *never* identify you as coming from `localhost`.

The issue here is your invocation of the `mysql` command line client with the `-P` (`--port`) option, without a corresponding `-H` (`--host`) argument.  Without `--host`, `--port` is ignored (this appears to be undocumented, but makes sense if you think about it -- an IP port without an associated IP host doesn't have any well-defined meaning).

You are actually connecting to your local machine over the unix socket.  (`SET GLOBAL LOG_WARNINGS = 2;` on your local MySQL instance and you'll see these failed logins in your local MySQL error log.)

```
$ mysql -H 127.0.0.1 -P 3308 -u testuser -p
```

...is the combination of options you're looking for.